# Intel assembly vs Intrinsics, AVX

Tags: c++, performance, compiler-optimization, intrinsics, avx

I have a simple vector-vector addition algorithm (c = a + b * lambda) written in intel assembly, using AVX instructions.
Here is my code:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; Dense to dense
;; Uses cache
;; AVX
;; Without tolerances
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

global _denseToDenseAddAVX_cache_64_linux
_denseToDenseAddAVX_cache_64_linux:

push    rbp
mov     rbp, rsp

; rdi: address1
; rsi: address2
; rdx: address3
; rcx: count
; xmm0: lambda

mov     rax, rcx
shr     rcx, 3
and     rax, 0x07

vzeroupper

vmovupd  ymm5, [abs_mask]

sub     rsp, 8
vmovlpd  [rbp - 8], xmm0
vbroadcastsd    ymm7, [rbp - 8]
vmovapd     ymm6, ymm7

cmp     rcx, 0
je      after_loop_denseToDenseAddAVX_cache_64_linux

start_denseToDenseAddAVX_cache_64_linux:

vmovapd  ymm0, [rdi] ; a
vmovapd  ymm1, ymm7
vmulpd   ymm1, [rsi] ; b
vaddpd   ymm0, ymm1  ; ymm0 = c = a + b * lambda
vmovapd  [rdx], ymm0

vmovapd  ymm2, [rdi + 32] ; a
vmovapd  ymm3, ymm6
vmulpd   ymm3, [rsi + 32] ; b
vaddpd   ymm2, ymm3  ; ymm2 = c = a + b * lambda
vmovapd  [rdx + 32], ymm2

add     rdi, 64
add     rsi, 64
add     rdx, 64

loop    start_denseToDenseAddAVX_cache_64_linux

after_loop_denseToDenseAddAVX_cache_64_linux:

cmp     rax, 0
je      end_denseToDenseAddAVX_cache_64_linux

mov     rcx, rax

last_loop_denseToDenseAddAVX_cache_64_linux:

vmovlpd  xmm0, [rdi] ; a
vmovapd  xmm1, xmm7
vmulsd   xmm1, [rsi] ; b
vaddsd   xmm0, xmm1  ; xmm0 = c = a + b * lambda
vmovlpd  [rdx], xmm0

add     rdi, 8
add     rsi, 8
add     rdx, 8

loop    last_loop_denseToDenseAddAVX_cache_64_linux

end_denseToDenseAddAVX_cache_64_linux:

mov     rsp, rbp
pop     rbp
ret
```

People often suggest me to use intel intrinsics because it is much better and safer. Now I've implemented this algorithm as this:

```
void denseToDenseAddAVX_cache(const double * __restrict__ a, 
                              const double * __restrict__ b, 
                              double * __restrict__ c, 
                              size_t count, double lambda) {
    const size_t firstCount = count / 8;
    const size_t rem1 = count % 8;
    int i;
    __m256d mul = _mm256_broadcast_sd(&lambda);
    for (i = 0; i < firstCount; i++) {
        // c = a + b * lambda
        __m256d dataA1 = _mm256_load_pd(&a[i * 8]);
        __m256d dataC1 = _mm256_add_pd(dataA1, _mm256_mul_pd(_mm256_load_pd(&b[i * 8]), mul  ));
        _mm256_store_pd(&c[i * 8], dataC1);

        __m256d dataA2 = _mm256_load_pd(&a[i * 8 + 4]);
        __m256d dataC2 = _mm256_add_pd(dataA2, _mm256_mul_pd(_mm256_load_pd(&b[i * 8 + 4]), mul  ));
        _mm256_store_pd(&c[i * 8 + 4], dataC2);
    }
    const size_t secondCount = rem1 / 4;
    const size_t rem2 = rem1 % 4;
    if (secondCount) {
        __m256d dataA = _mm256_load_pd(&a[i * 8]);
        __m256d dataC = _mm256_add_pd(dataA, _mm256_mul_pd(_mm256_load_pd(&b[i * 8]), mul  ));
        _mm256_store_pd(&c[i * 8], dataC);
        i += 4;
    }
    for (; i < count; i++) {
        c[i] = a[i] + b[i] * lambda;
    }
}
```

My problem is that the assembly version is two times faster than the second one. What is the problem with the c++ version?

Comment: As for any performance related question:  Are you optimizing (`-O3`) your C++ code?

Comment: Which compiler, what options, and what hardware are you testing on?  I assume with the same caller?  If both callers are in the same test program, did you do an untimed warmup run first to get page faults out of the way, and get the CPU up to max turbo?

Comment: If your compiler can't beat this asm, you probably forgot to enable optimization or are testing it wrong.  `vmovapd  ymm1, ymm7` is not needed, use 3-operand AVX instructions like `vmulpd   ymm1, ymm7, [rsi]`.  Plus you use the slow-on-Intel `loop` instruction, bottlenecking this loop at 1 iteration (2 vectors) per 7 clock cycles.  https://agner.org/optimize/.  I think even if a compiler didn't unroll, and used indexed addressing modes defeating micro-fusion and the port 7 store-AGU on Intel, it would still be at least as good as this.  Like GCC does: https://godbolt.org/z/MHgtfa

Comment: BTW, you can handle uneven counts by doing the last up-to-8 elements with unaligned vector loads that potentially overlaps data you already loaded.  (Ends at the end of the array).  At least if your input size is known to be >=4 elements.

Comment: Also, don't use `vmovlpd` as a load unless you *want* to merges into the low element of an existing vector.  You want `vmovsd` to avoid a false dependency and extra ALU uop.

Comment: 1.: Yes, I tried -O3.
2.: CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2640M CPU @ 2.80GHz
3.: nasm version: 2.14.02
4.: g++ version: 4.9.2

Comment: A factor of 2 seems implausible.  Are you **sure** you allocated memory the same way for both, with the same alignment?  (Misaligned loads won't fault in the G++ output because it folds the loads into memory operands, not separate `vmovapd`).  And you did a warm up run to page-fault in the pages of `C[]`, instead of having that happen during the C version's run time?

Comment: Your G++ options are incomplete, but I assumed you were using `-march=native` (on your sandybridge) or `-mavx`. https://godbolt.org/z/tW_MkV shows GCC4.9.2 makes a loop that uses indexed addressing modes (costing extra uops to unlaminate), but it'll still going to bottleneck on cache or memory bandwidth pretty easily: on SnB a 256-bit load or store takes 2 cycles in a load or store port.  Looks like 14 fused-domain uops per iteration (so it can issue 1 iter per 4 cycles).  With 2x 2 cycles per iteration of saturating the load-data and store-data ports, it can run 1 per 4 cycles.

Comment: Any downsides in G++'s code-gen are more than cancelled by your use of the slow `loop` instruction (7 uops, 1 per 5-cycle throughput on your Sandybridge CPU).  And G++ only has to do one register increment; the upside of indexed addressing modes.  For this to be a [mcve], we need more details on your test harness that calls these functions.  And maybe some investigations with `perf stat` or `perf record` of how / where G++'s code-gen is actually slow.

Answer (score 0):

A few things.

1. I think this is the most important one. Assembly code uses pointers arithmetic. Your C++ code doesn’t, you’re computing indices first, then taking addresses. Compilers often optimize to pointer math but this is not reliable, you better use same pointer math in your C++. What’s even worse, stuff like &a[i * 8 + 4] requires multiple integer instructions. The result in bytes is a+i*64+32, while x86 instructions can only scale integers for free by factors 2, 4 or 8. So the compiler has to emit left shift followed by add to compute the address. This issue doubles the count of instructions in the body of the loop.
2. C++ uses signed 32-bit integers for loop counters, assembly code uses unsigned 64-bit integers. For performance-critical code it’s often a good idea to use `size_t` in C++ for loop counters. BTW, if you would have set up “warnings as errors” setting in your C++ compiler, it would refuse to compile, saying something like “signed/unsigned mismatch”.
3. You have redundant loads in C++. CPUs can do math + one load with a single instruction. To do the same as assembly does, don’t use `_mm256_load_pd`, cast pointers from `const double *` into `const __m256d*`

Here’s slightly simplified example:

```
void denseToDenseAddAVX( const double *a, const double *b, double *c, size_t count, double lambda )
{
    assert( 0 == (size_t)( a ) % 32 );
    assert( 0 == (size_t)( b ) % 32 );
    assert( 0 == (size_t)( c ) % 32 );

    const double* const aEnd = a + count;
    const double* const aEndAligned = a + ( ( count / 4 ) * 4 );
    const __m256d mul = _mm256_set1_pd( lambda );
    while( a < aEndAligned )
    {
        const __m256d* const av = ( const __m256d* )a;
        const __m256d* const bv = ( const __m256d* )b;
        const __m256d cv = _mm256_add_pd( *av, _mm256_mul_pd( *bv, mul ) );
        _mm256_store_pd( c, cv );
        a += 4;
        b += 4;
        c += 4;
    }
    while( a < aEnd )
    {
        *c = ( *a ) + ( *b ) * lambda;
        a++;
        b++;
        c++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `_mm256_load_pd` optimizes identically to dereferencing a `__m256d*` (at least with GCC and clang).  Intrinsics are not asm; `_mm_load` intrinsics can be folded into memory-source operands.  Re: your other claims about things not optimizing well: you're being very specific about things like "twice as many instructions" based on some totally unverified assumptions about how dumb the compiler is going to be.  https://godbolt.org/z/z8t8Vg shows what the OP claims they ran (g++4.9.2 -O3).  Yes, indexed addressing modes so they unlaminate, but with a byte offset not braindead re-scaling.

Comment: And all loads did in fact fold into memory operands for ALU instructions.  (But like I said, with indexed addressing modes, defeating the benefit for uop issue throughput, only helping earlier in the front-end on the OP's SnB-family CPU.)

Comment: And BTW, your change to the OP's cleanup loop resulted in the cleanup loop *auto-vectorizing* with 256-bit vectors!!!  https://godbolt.org/z/FFRceU This is totally braindead of course; it only runs for less than 32 bytes left.  (Because you removed the OP's manual unroll, defeating most of the benefit of pointer-increment instead of indexed addressing modes.  Although you did achieve that goal you set out for.)  Some of this might have helped with clang (which unrolls by default), or with GCC PGO which enables `-funroll-loops`.